# IE 11 won't recognize parameters to angular $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

This works in Opera, Firefox, chrome, and safari but when I open up my Angular App in IE 11, I get an error:

> SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'
>
> controllers.js (386,17)

At line 386, this is the code:

```
  $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server/insertTicket.php',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            },
            data, // <--- line 386
            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    formData.append(key, value);
                });

                var headers = headersGetter();
                delete headers['Content-Type'];

                return formData;
            }
        })
        .success(function (data) {
          ...... more code here ..... }
```

Where is it expected a colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data, // <--- line 386
```

must be:

```
data: data, // <--- line 386
```

because it's a field of an object. I'm not sure why Firefox/Chrome eat this, but IE is very picky (and correct) here.

Comment: Should note that the former short-hand approach is part of ES2015, and works as expected in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @KentaGoto if it fixed your problem - can you accept the answer please? :)

Comment: Give me 7 minutes @DmitriyKhudorozhkov!

Comment: @KentaGoto no rush )